# How to compare two arrays that contain user details as array and remove the matching elements from one array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I've two arrays `$a` and `$b` containing 'user details' in arrays.

Following is the structure of it(i.e. output of `print_r()`)

```
print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
            [user_id] => 109
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-109
            [full_name] => Hiten Patel
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile_100.png
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
            [user_id] => 1585
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-1585
            [full_name] => Sushil Kadam
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 1585%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/1585_100_square.jpg
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
            [user_id] => 185
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-185
            [full_name] => Perceus Mody
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 185%s.peg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/185_100_square.peg
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
            [user_id] => 196
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-196
            [full_name] => Ira Hampton
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile.png
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
            [user_id] => 244
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => Hiten Patel
            [gender] => 2
            [user_image] => 244%s.cza
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/244_100_square.cza
    ) 
)
```

The second array is as follows :

```
print_r($b);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 244
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => Hiten Patel
            [gender] => 2
            [user_image] => 244%s.cza
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1585
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-1585
            [full_name] => Sushil Kadam
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 1585%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => 
        )

)
```

Now I want to compare the two arrays `$a and $b` and finally I want refined array `$a` which will not contain common array elements as follows(the array keys should start from 0 and keep on increasing by 1).

```
print_r($a); //after refinement, the desired output array

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 109
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-109
            [full_name] => Hiten Patel
            [gender] => 0
            [user_image] => 
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile_100.png
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 185
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-185
            [full_name] => Perceus Mody
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 185%s.peg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/185_100_square.peg
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 196
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-196
            [full_name] => Ira Hampton
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => 
            [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile.png
        )    
)
```

For achieving this desired output result I tried following code bu couldn't get the desired refined output result as I expected.

```
//My attempted code
$a = $result=array_diff($a,$b);
```

I also tried `array_diff_assoc()` function but that also didn't give me the desired output result.

Can someone please guide me in this regard in order to bring the desired output result?

Comment: Ist megre them and than use foreach loop and make a new array that values do u wany

Comment: @devpro:It would be better if you could post your code as an answer so that I can test the same and accept it as an answer. Could you please do the same?

Comment: I have updated the answer with unique values and index start from 0

Comment: I assume issue has been resolved my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an array containing the difference between two supplied user lists.

1) Given two arrays:

- a full user list ($userListA)
- a required list of users ($userListB)

Generate an array the contains the users that are in $userListA but *not* in $userListB.

[working example - eval.in](https://eval.in/492883); [Source code - pastebin](http://pastebin.com/U7XRZxE4)

There is a more efficient version that will be rather faster in large arrays. It uses a array 'keyed' on `user_id` so can check for missing without scanning all the array. [pastebin - compare array for missing user - quick](http://pastebin.com/6veUvUEg)

the code:

```
/*
 * This version is simple but will be slow for large arrays...
 *
 * Hmm... I may want to do a more efficient version later,  so I will use a
 *        compare function now, so that I can easily change it later.
 */

/*
 * Out Array:
 *    1) In $userListA but not in $userListB
 */
$diffAfromB = array();

// check the input user list...
foreach ($userListA as $userA) {

    // find the userA details in Array B
    if (!matchUserAinB($userA, $userListB)) {
        $diffAfromB[] = $userA;
    }
}

// show otput...
var_dump($diffAfromB);

exit;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Check if userA exists in userListB
 *
 * @param array $userA
 * @param array $userListB
 * @return boolean
 */
function matchUserAinB($userA, array $userListB)
{
    $found = false;

    foreach ($userListB as $userB) {
        if ($userB['user_id'] === $userA['user_id']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

The output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'user_id' => string '109' (length=3)
      'profile_page_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_name' => string 'profile-109' (length=11)
      'full_name' => string 'Hiten Patel' (length=11)
      'gender' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_image' => string '\"\"' (length=4)
      'is_invisible' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_group_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'language_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'profile_image' => string 'http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile_100.png' (length=92)
  1 => 
    array
      'user_id' => string '185' (length=3)
      'profile_page_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_name' => string 'profile-185' (length=11)
      'full_name' => string 'Perceus Mody' (length=12)
      'gender' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user_image' => string '185%s.peg' (length=9)
      'is_invisible' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_group_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'language_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'profile_image' => string 'http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/185_100_square.peg' (length=58)
  2 => 
    array
      'user_id' => string '196' (length=3)
      'profile_page_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_name' => string 'profile-196' (length=11)
      'full_name' => string 'Ira Hampton' (length=11)
      'gender' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user_image' => string '2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg' (length=46)
      'is_invisible' => string '0' (length=1)
      'user_group_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'language_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      'profile_image' => string 'http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile.png' (length=88)
```

The test data:

```
$sA = 'a:5:{i:0;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:3:"109";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:11:"profile-109";s:9:"full_name";s:11:"Hiten Patel";s:6:"gender";s:1:"0";s:10:"user_image";s:4:"\"\"";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"6";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";s:13:"profile_image";s:92:"http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile_100.png";}i:1;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:4:"1585";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:12:"profile-1585";s:9:"full_name";s:12:"Sushil Kadam";s:6:"gender";s:1:"0";s:10:"user_image";s:10:"1585%s.jpg";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"7";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";s:13:"profile_image";s:59:"http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/1585_100_square.jpg";}i:2;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:3:"185";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:11:"profile-185";s:9:"full_name";s:12:"Perceus Mody";s:6:"gender";s:1:"1";s:10:"user_image";s:9:"185%s.peg";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"6";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";s:13:"profile_image";s:58:"http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/185_100_square.peg";}i:3;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:3:"196";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:11:"profile-196";s:9:"full_name";s:11:"Ira Hampton";s:6:"gender";s:1:"1";s:10:"user_image";s:46:"2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"6";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";s:13:"profile_image";s:88:"http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile.png";}i:4;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:3:"244";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:11:"profile-244";s:9:"full_name";s:11:"Hiten Patel";s:6:"gender";s:1:"2";s:10:"user_image";s:9:"244%s.cza";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"7";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";s:13:"profile_image";s:58:"http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/244_100_square.cza";}}';
$userListA = unserialize($sA);

$sB = 'a:2:{i:0;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:3:"244";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"user_server_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:11:"profile-244";s:9:"full_name";s:11:"Hiten Patel";s:6:"gender";s:1:"2";s:10:"user_image";s:9:"244%s.cza";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"7";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:10:{s:7:"user_id";s:4:"1585";s:15:"profile_page_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"user_server_id";s:1:"0";s:9:"user_name";s:12:"profile-1585";s:9:"full_name";s:12:"Sushil Kadam";s:6:"gender";s:1:"0";s:10:"user_image";s:10:"1585%s.jpg";s:12:"is_invisible";s:1:"0";s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"7";s:11:"language_id";s:1:"0";}}';
$userListB = unserialize($sB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it but change indexes as per your array its just an example how can you solve your issue:

```
$a = array(
        array('userid'=>109,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test',
            'lang'=>0),
        array('userid'=>10,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test2',
            'lang'=>0),
        array('userid'=>101,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test',
            'lang'=>0),
        );
$b = array(
        array('userid'=>100,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test',
            'lang'=>0),
        array('userid'=>1011,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test2',
            'lang'=>0),
        array('userid'=>101,
            'profile_img'=>0,
            'username'=>'test',
            'lang'=>0),
        );



$newArr1 = array();

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $newArr1[$value['userid']] = $value;    
}

foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    $newArr2[$value['userid']] = $value;    
}
echo "<pre>";
$diffArr1 = array_diff_key($newArr1, $newArr2);
$diffArr2 = array_diff_key($newArr2, $newArr1);

$finalArr = array_merge($diffArr1,$diffArr2);
print_r($finalArr);
```

**Result looks like:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 109
            [profile_img] => 0
            [username] => test
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 10
            [profile_img] => 0
            [username] => test2
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 100
            [profile_img] => 0
            [username] => test
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 1011
            [profile_img] => 0
            [username] => test2
            [lang] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. I want to make one thing clear that I don't want common elements in resultant array. You have added the element with user_id 109 in your answer, actually it should not be added and also the keys in a new array should start from 0 and keep on increasing by 1. Could you please modify your answer accordingly. I think you are very close to what I needed actually. Thanks once again, waiting for your reply keenly.

Comment: All right u r looking for rearrange array answer updated @user2839497

Comment: The common array elements should also not get repeat in resultant array.

Comment: @user2839497: answer updated again with unique values

Comment: You are not using $c in your code after array_merge?

Comment: Sorry no need to merge them ignore $c I have rwmoved

Answer (score 0):

first of all i give the `$output` the `$a` to get all elements in `$a`

after that i compare it with `$b` and remove the exists value in `$output`

```
    $output = $a;
    foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
        $exists = false;
        foreach($output as $key => $value) {
            if ($v == $value) {
                unset($output[$key]);
                $exists = true;
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } 
        if (!$exists) {
            $output[] = $v;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    echo '</pre>';
```

**THE RESULT**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 109
                [profile_page_id] => 0
                [user_name] => profile-109
                [full_name] => Hiten Patel
                [gender] => 0
                [user_image] => 
                [is_invisible] => 0
                [user_group_id] => 6
                [language_id] => 
                [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile_100.png
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 185
                [profile_page_id] => 0
                [user_name] => profile-185
                [full_name] => Perceus Mody
                [gender] => 1
                [user_image] => 185%s.peg
                [is_invisible] => 0
                [user_group_id] => 6
                [language_id] => 
                [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/185_100_square.peg
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 196
                [profile_page_id] => 0
                [user_name] => profile-196
                [full_name] => Ira Hampton
                [gender] => 1
                [user_image] => 2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg
                [is_invisible] => 0
                [user_group_id] => 6
                [language_id] => 
                [profile_image] => http://app.campusknot.com/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/noimage/profile.png
            )    
    )
```